# Error when trying to display Image in Java

Tags: java

Here's a programme to display an image using the Processing Library.

When I try to run this program, I get below error:

> Usage: PApplet [options]  [sketch args] 
>   See the Javadoc for PApplet for an explanation.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import processing.core.*;
        public class MyPApplet extends PApplet {
        String image = "http://blog.forbestravelguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/2.La-Jolla-Shores-Beach5.jpg";
        PImage backgroundImg;

    public void setup()
    {
        size(200,200);
        backgroundImg = loadImage(image,"jpg");
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        image(backgroundImg, 0, 0, 0, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done what it says? Have you read the Javadoc? What does it say? What do you not understand?

Comment: Well the Javadoc is huge and I can't find any reference to this problem there.